# When should we separate common parts of multiple services into one separated service

Tags: database-design, microservices

We have some services (consider 10, some of them already exist and some are yet to come). All of these services have a common part where they keep track of what's being changed, and these so-called "logs" are shown to users, and the persisting/searching pattern is also common in between all of them (searching might be different in some few parameters). So each service has 2 separate tables, namely `log_action` and `log_details`. The first one keeps the higher-level action that happened, and the latter one keeps the details (1-n relationship), consider the following:

```
User <USERNAME> changed <BIGGER_ENTITY_NAME>'s <FIELD_NAME> on <DATE_TIME>(stored in log_action):
    - Changed the <FIELD_NAME> of item <ACTUAL_ENTITY> from <FROM>$ to <TO>$. (stored in log_details)
    - Changed the <FIELD_NAME> of item <ACTUAL_ENTITY> from <FROM>$ to <TO>$. (stored in log_details)
    ... (stored in log_details)
```

I have 2 approaches in mind:

1. Creating a dedicated log service (using a NoSQL to achieve flexibility)(with the appropriate SDK for client usages):

   - (+) This approach reduces boilerplate code and tables
   - (+) Takes less time-effort, specially helpful for our new service developments
   - (?) It probably can be considered as a whole service, it manages some resources called "logs"
   - (-) Yet it's keeping some data which is basically owned by other services
2. Let each service manage their own logs (almost all of these services use RDBMS):

   - (+) Actions are private to the service
   - (-) Takes more effort developing new services

Now my question is, what is the best practice here and why? Should we consider a separate logging service? Or let each service do this on their own? Or anything else maybe?

Comment: In this specific case, I would recommend using existing logging services. I don't think your specific usage is special enough to justify custom implementation.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "service" in this context

Comment: @Ewan I mean a layer composed of an application with its dedicated database which takes care of its resources and the logic implemented on top of those resources. Not sure if this really is a good definition of a "service". I'm also not sure if my explanation here is helpful, if you need more details let me know so I can come up with an appropriate example.

Comment: @Euphoric Thanks, do you also have some specific suggestions accordingly? I looked up a bit, but couldn't find an existing service that suffices my needs. Maybe I should correct myself when I say a "logging service", what I actually mean is an "auditing service".

Comment: I can't get over the feeling that "log" should be replaced by something more domain-specific. Users do not typically view "logs". IT administrators and system maintainers usually view "logs". Are you sure you don't have some cross-cutting business concern at play here?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I should correct myself that what I mean by "log" is not application log. Maybe auditing business-level changes to users who own some resource would be more specific. Here's an example, imagine some people working for a hotel, and some users (hotel owner, chain manager, hotel manager, receptionist, etc,...) should be able to see changes throughout time concerning their hotel. I'm not sure if "log" is a valid term for this.

Comment: It is an audit log, for sure. A perfectly reasonable thing to expect a system to do. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

If the shared part is extensive, you could use a [Monorepo](https://monorepo.tools/) so that the logging code is maintained only once, but deployed in several different microservices. This avoids adding network logic to what should be simple functionality, and also the overhead of running a node that doesn't contribute to solving the domain tasks.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yeah I didn't even came up with the idea of `Monorepo`. I'll make sure to take a look and accept your answer if it helped me in this use case.

Comment: A monorepo is one poasible way of doing it, but several others exist, such as a Nuget/npm package. Monorepos are imho a heavyhanded approach if all you need is one reusable library.

Answer (score 0):

yes you should, however, you have to ensure that your solution is performant. Logging doesn't lend itself to "normal" REST style apis over HTTP

For example. If you are simply writing whatever you receive to a nosql db, how much "server side" logic do you need? can a shared logging component be 90% a wrapper of the db client?

Similarly if you are writing to syslog or windows events, the client side code is really all already there. You have a second out of process component pick up the various local logs and combine them on your reporting platform.

Performance is everything with logging, because you tend to have a lot of data flowing and most of the time you don't want it to interfere with your applications primary process.